# Where should I put the "the"?

Tags: articles

I would like to express that one does not fulfill the requirements of being invited to an interview. So I wrote "Not qualified for the invitation for the interview". But I am not sure whether I should write:

1. Not qualified for the invitation for the interview
2. Not qualified for the invitation for interview
3. Not qualified for invitation for the interview

My question is therefore: Where should I put the "the" in this case?

Answer (score 1):

The context of this question is puzzling.

Suppose the qualifications for someone to be interviewed are that the person must have a doctorate in mathematics and experience in discrete mathematics. Under what circumstances would it make sense to invite for an interview people who have not yet graduated from college.

Suppose the qualifications for someone to interviewed are that the person must be older than 17. Under what circumstances would it make sense to require people to be older than 39 in order to be invited to an interview?

The point I am trying to make is that it is hard to write what you are trying to say because it seems to make no sense. Please explain why you would invite people to an interview in order for the interviewer to dismiss them as being unqualified even to be interviewed. Please explain why you would not invite to be interviewed people who qualify for an interview. In short, the idea that there is one set of qualifications for an invitation to be interviewed and a different set of qualifications to be interviewed needs to be explained before good wording can be found.

Of course if the qualifications for an interview and the qualifications for an invitation to be interviewed are the same, your writing problem goes away

> not qualified for an interview

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The context here however is that the qualifications for an interview and the qualifications for an invitation to be interviewed are not the same. The candidates may be qualified for an interview but due to some reasons they are not qualified for being invited to an interview.

Comment: Well in that odd set of circumstances, you should say “you are not qualified for an invitation to be interviewed.”

Comment: Thanks a lot. What if I wanted to maintain the structure "invitation for interview", which of the above is fine?

Comment: “an invitation for an interview.” The definite article is ungrammatical.